# Match content by reading file using bash grep, string enclosed with [ and ] special character

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to match string contains [xyz] or [abc] from the file using bash grep which contains like:

## TEST_FILE:

```
Testing of pattern line no 1 [xyz]
Hi, this is just test file contains abc and/or xyz etc..
```

## Tried code:

```
if ( grep -iq "\[xyz\]" "$TEST_FILE" ); then
  PATTERN_MATCH="xyz matched"
elif ( grep -iq "\[abc\]" "$TEST_FILE" ); then
  PATTERN_MATCH="abc matched"
fi
```

The problem is, it always matches although by passing xyz/abc instead of [xyz]/[abc].

File content can match to case-insensitive [XYZ] or [ABC] but with just xyz or abc. [ and ] special character enclosed with string. Can someone point the issue or solution for same due to [ and ] special character? I tried other ways using grep and egrep too but no luck!

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: yeah, need more details, though the script can be improved (no need parantheses, use `-F` for fixed string matching, use single quotes for search argument, lowercase variable names, etc), the given bash snippet doesn't seem to have an error as such..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to check the exit code of grep ( which should be checked with $? instead ). Here I have rewritten your code to work :

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST_FILE='./input.txt'

[[ $( grep -i '\[xyz\]' "$TEST_FILE" ) ]] && PATTERN_MATCH="xyz matched"
[[ $( grep -i '\[abc\]' "$TEST_FILE" ) ]] && PATTERN_MATCH="abc matched"

echo $PATTERN_MATCH
```

Hope it helps buddy!

Comment: Probably you're not aware of `-q` functionality in `grep`. There is no need to use command substitution here.

Comment: I know what **-q** does. Can you please provide a sample of how to test the exit code without using **$?** ?

Comment: It's just `if grep -q 'pattern' infile; then ...` or `grep -q 'pattern' infile && ...`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. First example foes not work on my system ( Centos 7); second one works though. Thanks!

Comment: That's weird, `-q` is even required by POSIX. Definitely works for me (both GNU grep 3.1 and BSD grep 2.5.1).